# Python - str() outputs non unicode

Tags: python

I'm using the [py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py) library to rename .flac files with information from its metadata.
I'm having a problem with getting a `LocalPath` object to a normal utf-8 string to run it into `subprocess`.

Here's the bit of code that goes wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This program takes the information from FLAC metadata to rename the files
# according to various naming paterns.

import subprocess
import sys
from py.path import local


# Defining the function that fetches metadata and formats it
def metadata(filename):
    filename = str(filename).decode("utf-8")

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["metaflac", "--show-tag=tracknumber", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    tracknumber, error = pipe.communicate()
    tracknumber = tracknumber.decode("utf-8")
    tracknumber = tracknumber.replace("tracknumber=", "")
    tracknumber = tracknumber.replace("TRACKNUMBER=", "")
    tracknumber = tracknumber.rstrip() # Remove whitespaces
    if int(tracknumber) < 10:
        if "0" in tracknumber:
            pass
        else: 
            tracknumber = "0" + tracknumber
    else:
        pass

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["metaflac", "--show-tag=title", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    title, error = pipe.communicate()
    title = title.decode("utf-8")
    title = title.replace("TITLE=", "")
    title = title.replace("title=", "")
    title = title.rstrip()

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        ["metaflac", "--show-tag=artist", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    artist, error = pipe.communicate()
    artist = artist.decode("utf-8")
    artist = artist.replace("ARTIST=", "")
    artist = artist.replace("artist=", "")
    artist = artist.rstrip()

    return tracknumber, title, artist


# Defining function that renames the files
def rename(root):
    if output == filename:
        print "%s is already named correctly\n" % (title)
    else:
        filename.rename(filename.new(basename=output))

# Importing command line arguments
try:
    root = local(sys.argv[2])
    option = sys.argv[1]
    print option, root
except ValueError:
    print "WTF!!!"

# Running
if option == "--s":
    for filename in root.visit(fil="*.flac", rec=True):
        tracknumber, title, artist = metadata(filename)
        output = "%s - %s" % (tracknumber, filename)
        rename(root)
print "Files renamed"
```

I'm using `filename = str(filename)` because `filename` is not a string, but a `LocalPath` and `subprocess` crashes when not given string.

The problem is that with utf-8 file name, `str(filename)` gives back something like this: `/media/Main/Musique/2 Bal 2 Neg'/3X plus efficace/09 - Po\xc3\xa8tes de la mort.flac`

Adding `filename = filename.decode("utf-8")` does not seem to change anything

I'm still very new to python :D

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but the use of global variables rather than arguments and return values makes your code very difficult to understand.

Comment: @Blckknght You mean I should be using 'return tracknumber, title, artist' instead of 'global tracknumber, artist, title'? Why?

Comment: @baldurmen because it makes it much clearer exactly *what* is modified *when* if you don't use mutable global state. Your final bug - the `UnboundLocalError` - *is* actually caused by using global variables.

Comment: @lvc Hmm, I edited my code according to your advice, but the `UnboundLocalError` still happens

Comment: @baldurmen see my answer. The problem isn't caused by *those* globals in particular, but by `filename` being global (although admittedly, if it wasn't, you would get a different error instead, and still need to make a similar modification to the one in my answer). This only *might* fix your Unicode problems, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnboundLocalError` you are getting at the end is because in this line:

```
filename = str(filename)
```

you are trying to treat `filename` as both a local and a global variable. You are (hopefully) not wanting to reassign the global (which would happen if you did `global filename` before this line). But when you assign it as a local, Python will not let you look up the global version of it anywhere in the function - if you do this before it is assigned, you get the error you are seeing. Choose a different variable name, or pass `filename` in as an argument - eg,

```
def metadata(filename):
    filename = str(filename)
    ...
    return tracknumber, title, artist

tracknumber, title, artist = metadata(filename)
```

will work.

To fix your unicode errors, you are mostly on the right track. You need to maintain the distiction at all times between bytes and (unicode) characters - in Python 2, use `str` for the former and `unicode` for the latter. If you upgrade to Python 3, you would use `bytes` for the former and `str` for the latter (and the distiction would be easier to maintain in a lot of cases). Use the `decode` method to go from bytes to unicode, and the `encode` method to go the other way.

You generally want to use bytes only when you are directly doing IO, and unicode everywhere else. The `subprocess` module accepts *either*, but for filenames it is usually easier to use unicode.

The `Py` library helpfully doesn't maintain, or acknowledge, this distinction at all. It just uses `str` internally, regardless of which Python version it is running on (it uses a single codebase for both Python 2.x and Python 3.x). This means in Python 2, you *do* want to decode it to `unicode`:

```
def metadata(filename):
   filename = str(filename).decode('utf-8')
```

but in Python 3, you want to leave it as a `str`:

```
def metadata(filename):
   filename = str(filename)
```

in both cases, you then want to only use `filename` in all your calls to `subprocess.Popen`, and *not* `str(filename)`. So,

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(
    ["metaflac", "--show-tag=title", str(filename)],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

should be:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(
    ["metaflac", "--show-tag=title", filename],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You want to do something similar with the metadata you do get back. `communicate` counts as direct IO, and so it returns bytes, not characters. You already try to convert two of your three bits of metadata like this:

```
title.decode("utf-8")
```

but that needs to be:

```
title = title.decode("utf-8")
```

you need to do the same for `artist`, and add the equivalent line for `tracknumber`.

Comment: It does get rid of `UnboundLocalError`, but then I'm still stuck with non utf-8 code and if I try `filename = unicode(filename)` I get it back... But thanks for showing me better practice!

Comment: @baldurmen does keeping the `filename = filename.decode('utf8')` from your question help? That *appears* to be the right approach, although Python 2 makes it hard to maintain the appropriate distinctions.

Comment: nope, it does not change anything actually. I get the same old non utf-8 string.

Comment: @baldurmen because you're converting the unicode object back to a string before you pass it into `POpen`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answers. Unfortunately, after implementing your suggestions, I get ol'`UnboundLocalError` again... See edited question for actual code

Comment: @baldurmen do you get the error at the same location, or at a different one? It might help if you edit in the full error.

Comment: nevermind last comment, I'm just really tired and wrote `output = "%s - %s" % (tracknumber, filename)` when it should have been `output = "%s - %s" % (tracknumber, **title**)`. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Use `unicode(filename)` instead of `str(filename)` as `unicode()` converts an object to a Unicode string while `str()` converts the object to a string.

Comment: I get this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 57: ordinal not in range(128)